# How can I get the value of the autocompleteTextView on button click?

Tags: c#, android, forms, xamarin, buttonclick

I would like some help. I have this code:

```
string hozzaadnivalo;

public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
        {

            View view = LayoutInflater.From(container.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.pager_item, container, false);
            container.AddView(view);

            Button hozzaadas = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.hozzaad);

            var autoCompleteOptions = new string[] { "Sajt", "Tej", "Kecske", "Barátnő", "piros", "alma" };
            ArrayAdapter autoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(container.Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line, autoCompleteOptions);
            AutoCompleteTextView mautoCompleteTextView = view.FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.autoCompleteTextView1);
            mautoCompleteTextView.Adapter = autoCompleteAdapter;

            hozzaadas.Click += hozaadasListViewhez;
            hozzaadnivalo = mautoCompleteTextView.Text;
        }
private void hozaadasListViewhez(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            adapter.Add(mautoCompleteTextView.Text);
            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

So i want to add the text of the autocompleteTextView to my listview adapter, but i cant do it there because it does not exist there. So I made a string that I makde equal to the mautoCompleteTextView.Text, but it will be empty, because it will run at the program start, when the user havent done anything. So my problem is that i cant get the mautoCompleteTextView.Text when the user has pressed the button. If anyone could halp that would be great thanks.

Comment: you need to declare mautoCompleteTextView at the class level so that it is accessible in other methods

Comment: and how sould i do it? Do i have to use a layoutinflater? Cuz its not in the main layout.

Comment: no.  This is a basic C# scoping problem.  It has nothing to do with Xamarin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `mautoCompleteTextView` inside your method, so it is only available locally within that method.

If you move the declaration outside of the method, then `mautoCompleteTextView` will be available throughout the entire class.

```
// declare it here
AutoCompleteTextView mautoCompleteTextView;

// then instantiate it within the method
public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
       ... // code omitted

       mautoCompleteTextView = view.FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.autoCompleteTextView1);

       ... // code omitted
    }
```